# How to return the object when using MockedStatic in Java?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I need to mock a static class and bind it during the service start up time. Following https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/, I set up mockedstatic for the class and expectation. I want to know how I can returned the mocked class T not MockedStatic?

```
public static MyClass mockClass() {
  try (MockedStatic<MyClass> myClass = Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)) {
        myClass.when(() -> MyClass.getMetho(Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn("abc");
        return myClass;
  }}
```

**return myClass** doesn't work. How can I strip MyClass from MockedStatic?

Comment: You need to initialize your service inside the try block.

Comment: This doesn't make difference. myClass has visibility inside try block, the problem is, myClass is the type of MockedStatic<..>, while it requires to return the type of MyClass.

Comment: 1. firstly, with the current signature, you are returning an instance of your class containing static methods, which is certainly not the intention. 2. This is not you how you use mockStatic. You can only use the static class inside the try block. Note that this is try-with-resources, so if you exit the try block, static class is no longer patched. To summarize, the approach you are trying to take is wrong, entire service initialization and usage must be in the try block.